# Template template parameter argument names usage

Tags: c++, template-templates

In the code

```
template < template<class TTP> class TP > ... // whatever
```

is `TTP` usable anywhere at all then? Can't find any reference to what happens with these names in the Standard.

Comment: I wonder why you're asking. Is it so that you can capture `container<value>` where `container` is something like `vector` or `list` and `value` is `int` or `std::string`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Exactly! And I wanted to avoid the `<class T, template<class=T> ...>` thing.

Comment: I've done that before, but I can't quite remember. I'm pretty sure it's straightforward. I'm trying now

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yep, I got it working and just wondered if it can be refined any further -- have never used the template template args before :)

Comment: I've added such an answer. We might need to edit the question at some point - your real question is subtly different from what you ask. Given a type `T`, which we know is of the form `container_template<value_type>`, you want to get access separately to both `container_template` and `value_type`.

Comment: ... actually, do you really need the `container_type` (to specialize on, or to put 'new' value_types into)? Or is it sufficient to simply get `value_type`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid https://ideone.com/rcbnV1

Comment: How about simply `template<typename T> auto get_keys(const & T m) -> decltype(m.begin()->first)`?

Comment: I've added another answer that answers your question more directly. Yes you can access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[basic.scope.temp]/p1:

> The declarative region of the name of a template parameter of a
>   template *template-parameter* is the smallest *template-parameter-list*
>   in which the name was introduced.

It can be used inside that list, and that's it. For instance,

```
template < template<class T, T t> class TP > class foo {};
//                           ^  ^-----T's scope ends here
//                           |
//                           T can be used here

foo<std::integral_constant> bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it, you just have to be slightly indirect about it.

```
                        /--- don't bother giving this a name.
                        |
                        |             Put it here instead ------------------\                                 |
                        |                                                   |
                        V                                                   V
template<template<typename, typename ...> class container_tmpl, typename value_t>
void foo(container_tmpl<value_t> x) {
    std:: cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std:: endl;
}
```

More precisely, if you have an object of type `vector<int>` and you pass it to `foo` above, then `foo` can access the relevant type parameters:

```
vector<int> v;
bar(v);
```

When `bar(v)` is called, then `bar` "knows" the first parameter, which (I think?) is your goal.

I'm not saying the other answers are incorrect, it's just that you asked slightly the wrong question.

To understand the answer I've given, it's probably easier to forget about the `template` line and instead look at:

```
/* complex template-template gibberish */
void foo(container_tmpl<value_t> x) {
```

The type of `x`, the parameter to `foo`, is of type `container_tmpl<value_t>`. Where `container_tmpl` is something like `vector` or `list`, and `value_t` is something like `int` or `std::string`. Once you write this signature, it's obvious that `value_t` is simple a type (and hence becomes `typename value_t` in the template introduction) and that `container_tmpl` is a template taking (at least) one type parameter.

In this context, `value_t` and `container_tmpl` are defined inside `bar`.

If you don't understand why I have `typename ...`, then remember that `vector` actually takes two type args, not one. Anyway, the basic idea is that you must provide names for these template args *outside* where you would expect to get them. E.g. if you have a template that takes three arguments, two type parameters and an integer.

```
template< template<typename,int,typename> class the_template, typename T1, int I, typename T2>
void foo(the_template<T1,I,T2> x);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did and wondered if it can be simplified somehow. But the question was really about the standard, which I'm not too strong in... By the way, I appreciate your suggestion regarding `decltype` and consider going that route instead of bloody variadic template templates! =)

Answer (score 0):

No. It's a template parameter for TP<>, not the outer template function.

Comment: I see, but what does the Standard say about them?

Comment: I would like to avoid that mess this early in the morning. Don't want to ruin a perfectly normal day.

Comment: @Blob Well, it's the evening for me here :D